# Checking String using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check that a string follows a particular format using Regex. For example the user enters in the console:

**next 33**

Which then activates an if statement which checks if it follows the format "next (digit)(digit)".

```
if ("next \\d\\d".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
   //further code
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if (command.matches("next //d//d")) {
   //further code
}
```

From what I have read //d can be any digit 0-9. So I can't understand why this does not work. It seems like I should be able to checking a line like above but I have very little experience with Regex.

I am sorry for this elemetary quesion. Thank you.

Comment: The second one should work, assuming you fix the slash's orientation (should be `"\\"` not `"//"`), the input is actually getting recorded to `command`, and that the input is `next 33` (case sensitive)... The first method won't work, as `equalsIgnoreCase` is a case-insensitive, but direct comparison, not a regex match... Additionally, consider changing ` \\d\\d` to ` \\d{2}`, as it makes for better readability... Lastly, read the [Pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), it will help you understand regex syntax and proper use.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off. You want `String.matches(String)` and the order matters. This

```
if ("next \\d\\d".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
    // ...
```

should be

```
if (command.matches("next \\d\\d")) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
String pattern = "next (\\d){2}";
String command = "next 33";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(command);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("TRUE");
} else {
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```